# What is the purpose of using references to function and to IO objects (as arguments)?

Tags: c++, io, reference

Why are references to IO streams used instead of streams itself?And the same question about reference to the function.Trying to study this topic I still can't understand it.

In the code below function only prints result from the given  `QueryResult` object on its given stream.

```
//declaration  
 ostream & print(ostream & os, const QueryResult &qr);
```

Comment: Because streams aren't copy-able? And why would you want to pass and return streams by value anyway?

Comment: I don't. It's only example from book)

Comment: You might want to switch to the chapter dealing with references and such.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "reference to function" here. The first `&` is part of the return type.

```
ostream& print(ostream& os, const QueryResult& qr);
```

The function returns a `ostream&` and takes a `ostream&` as parameter, because streams cannot be copied. The `QueryResult` is passed as constant reference to avoid a possibly expensive copy.

Answer (score 2):

As you must know already that during function call arguments are copied to the function's parameters. But IO classes don't allow to copy their objects. Hence we cannot pass object(istream or ostream ) directly. or in simpler words

> Because we can’t copy the IO types, we cannot have a parameter or return type that
>   is one of the stream types. Functions that do IO typically pass and
>   return the stream through references.

one more thing.

> Reading or writing an IO object changes its state, so the reference must not be const

Answer (score 0):

It is useful in method chaining. The aim is to return a fresh reference to a stream that can be passed along to the next call of operator<<() in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

IO object can't be copied so we can't have return or parameter of IO type. So to do IO operation we must pass reference to the IO object to do  cascading.